# Cant set the 'action' in FB.AppRequest

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-unity-sdk

I am trying to implement in my game a request that will function as an 'Ask for help' request.
The user will send this request to his friend, and if the user helps him, I need to know about it.

After looking over all the documentation, I came up with this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests#implementation

It says that I need to add an extra parameter, especifing the action to be executed.

Here is an example copied from the doc:

```
FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
  message: 'Take this bomb to blast your way to victory!',
  to: {user-ids}
  action_type:'send',
  object_id: 'YOUR_OBJECT_ID'  // i.e. '191181717736427' 
}, requestCallback);
```

When I try to do this with Unity, I dont have nearly the same parameters (in FB.AppRequest). Is there something I'm missing? How can I achieve this behaviour in Unity?

Comment: Wondering the same thing...

Answer (score 0):

This is only present in the Javascript SDK.  Currently the Unity SDK does not have this yet.

Answer (score 0):

The newest unity SDK (5.1) is implemented the missing function.